# Naming multiple css files when minifying with Grunt

Tags: css, node.js, gruntjs, minify, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I have multiple css files that I'm minifying, is there a way to keep each of the minified files the same name as their css file? So for example, billing_edit.css, checkout.css, error_page.css would minify into billing_edit.min.css, checkout.min.css, error_page.min.css. Theres a lot of css files and normally I know its better to combine them, but this is a situation where there are potentially conflicting styles. So in that case I want to avoid doing the below.

```
cssmin: {
      options: {
        compatibility: 'ie8'
      },
      dist: {
        files: {
          'stylesheets/billing_edit.min.css' : [
            'stylesheets/billing_edit.css'
          ],
          'stylesheets/checkout.min.css' : [
            'stylesheets/checkout.css'
          ],
          'stylesheets/error_page.min.css' : [
            'stylesheets/error_page.css'
          ],
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use multiple `dist`

```
cssmin: {
    options: {
       compatibility: 'ie8'
    },
    dist1: {
        files: {
            'stylesheets/billing_edit.min.css' : [
                'stylesheets/billing_edit.css'
            ]
        }
    },
    dist2: {
        files: {
            'stylesheets/checkout.min.css' : [
                'stylesheets/checkout.css'
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

etc.